# Postgres update column, on conflict ignore this row

Tags: sql, postgresql, sql-update

I have a table with `email` and `secondary_email`. `email` column has a unique constraint, while `secondary_email` can be repeated across rows.

I have to write a query to copy `secondary_email` to `email`. If there is a conflict, then ignore **this row.**

This query

```
UPDATE users SET email = secondary_email
WHERE NOT EXISTS
(SELECT 1 FROM users WHERE email=secondary_email)
```

still throws the error `ERROR: duplicate key value violates unique constraint "users_email_key"`

**Users Before**

```
+----+-------+-----------------+
| id | email | secondary_email |
+----+-------+-----------------+
| 1  | NULL  | NULL            |
| 2  | NULL  | NULL            |
| 3  | NULL  |                 |
| 4  | NULL  | e1@example.com  |
| 5  | NULL  | e1@example.com  |
| 6  | NULL  | e2@example.com  |
+----+-------+-----------------+
```

**Users After**

```
+----+----------------+-----------------+
| id | email          | secondary_email |
+----+----------------+-----------------+
| 1  | NULL           | NULL            |
| 2  | NULL           | NULL            |
| 3  | NULL           |                 |
| 4  | e1@example.com | e1@example.com  |
| 5  | NULL           | e1@example.com  |
| 6  | e2@example.com | e2@example.com  |
+----+----------------+-----------------+
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need table aliases to fix your query:

```
UPDATE users u
    SET email = u.secondary_email
    WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM users u2 WHERE u2.email = u.secondary_email);
```

For your overall problem, check for no duplicates within the column as well:

```
UPDATE users u
    SET email = u.secondary_email
    FROM (SELECT secondary_email, COUNT(*) as cnt
          FROM users u
          GROUP BY secondary_email
          HAVING COUNT(*) = 1
         ) s
    WHERE s.secondary_email = u.secondary_email AND
          NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM users u2 WHERE u2.email = u.secondary_email);
```

Or choose the first one:

```
UPDATE users u
    SET email = u.secondary_email
    FROM (SELECT u.*,
                 ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY secondary_email ORDER BY user_id) as seqnum
          FROM users u
         ) s
    WHERE s.user_id = u.user_id AND
          s.seqnum = 1 AND
          NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM users u2 WHERE u2.email = u.secondary_email);
```

Note:  This will also filter out `NULL` values which seems like a good idea.

[Here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_12&fiddle=af28ab58ec8f30e09670f24499c1ca16) is a db<>fiddle.

Comment: Still getting the same violates unique constraint error

Comment: Note.  You will get the duplicate error if more than one secondary_email columns are the same.  Once you update one row, you will get an error trying to update another one.  The where clause is evaluated before you start the update so it will not eliminate those.

Comment: @Gordon Your last query did work, but only updated the first row with `secondary_email`

Comment: @Gordon I removed `s.seqnum = 1` in your last query hoping that it would update all rows. But now I am getting the same duplicate key error.

Comment: @BjarniRagnarsson added Before and After user tables for example.

Comment: @jerrymouse . . . Ooops.  The last query was missing its `partition by` clause.

Comment: @GordonLinoff Thanks for your time. But it still gives the same duplicate key error, despite `partition by`.

Comment: @jerrymouse . . . Is the data being modified as you are executing this?

Comment: No, it is all static data.

Comment: @jerrymouse . . . The `join` condition was wrong -- generating duplicates.  It should be on the user id.

Comment: Worked this time! A small correction, `user_id` should be in the `s` table.